# How to show the total count of items in a task list on a seperate page in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, list, view, task-list

I have a task list that I'd like to be able to reference on a page - specifically the total number of items in the list. I've been looking through the web parts and haven't really found anything that works. Is there another way to do it?

EDIT: I am trying to grab data from a particular VIEW within the list, so REST will not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can try following steps :

step 1: GoTo modify this view

step 2: Totals. Here you can Select one or more totals to display.
(Refer below image. Here I have selected 'Title' field and in dropdown select 'Count'. You can use this for 'ID' field as well)

[image]

Step 3 : Done
(You can inset this list view directly on your page through insert web part)

Below is the output of above steps:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can write REST for the same. Below is the example how rest will look like.

**SiteURL**/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/**ListName**/$count