# SharePoint & jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery

I have a SharePoint custom list called CIW that has a column called Status and this has the following possible values;

"Completed", "In Progress", "Not Started" & "Cancelled".

I would like jQuery to run against the list and get a total of each of the Status, e.g.

"Completed"=20, "In Progress"=11, "Not Started"=15 & "Cancelled"=3

If possible output the results to a table.

Comment: T here is out of the box way to achieve this. Refer this solution - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220935/how-to-show-the-total-count-of-items-in-a-task-list-on-a-seperate-page-in-sharep/220948#220948

Comment: You can set count for multiple fields like this ....

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of **OOTB option** available I would recommend you to try this before you want to code for it.

1. Create new view select the columns you want to display then `GroupBy based on 'Status'` column.
2. As mentioned in your comments filter the column to show 'Count'.

> Conside first option if your interested in-build Expand/Collapse in addition to the total count.

Code option:

- Achieve this using **CSR** - Refer [MSDN code samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a), [CSR basics and code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output the results to a table using jQuery, the following code for your reference:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {    
    var listName="CIW";

    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                  "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('"+listName+"')/items?$select=Status";

    //execute AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            var completedCount=0,inProgressCount=0,notStartedCount=0,cancelledCount=0;

            for(var i=0;i<data.d.results.length;i++){
                var item=data.d.results[i];
                if(item.Status=="Completed"){
                    completedCount++;
                }else if(item.Status=="In Progress"){
                    inProgressCount++;
                }else if(item.Status=="Not Started"){
                    notStartedCount++;
                }else if(item.Status=="Cancelled"){
                    cancelledCount++;
                }
            }
            var html="<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><thead><tr><th>Status</th><th>Count</th></tr></thead>";
            html+="<tbody><tr><td>Completed</td><td>"+completedCount+"</td></tr>";
            html+="<tr><td>In Progress</td><td>"+inProgressCount+"</td></tr>";
            html+="<tr><td>Not Started</td><td>"+notStartedCount+"</td></tr>";
            html+="<tr><td>Cancelled</td><td>"+cancelledCount+"</td></tr></tbody></table>";
            $("#CIWCount").html(html);
        },
        error: function () {
            //alert("Failed to get details");                
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="CIWCount"></div>
```

[image]